# Where can I find a list of all available Hexadecimal icons like these?

Tags: html, css

I found a tutorial about adding hexadecimal icons to the front of html buttons, and would like to see a list of all possible icons.

Is there a list somewhere, or do I have to manually check each number to find out what is available to use?

Here is a sample of one of them:

```
.save:before, input[type="submit"]:before {content: "\2714";}
```

And here is the tutorial I got it from:

http://www.red-team-design.com/just-another-awesome-css3-buttons

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are [Unicode code points](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2714/index.htm) and there are quite a few of them :-)

Those particular ones are related to Windows Dingbats characters.

You can change the `2714` in that link to get the other ones, or you can select individual ones from the entire [Dingbats block](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/dingbats/images.htm) (warning, this may take some time to load due to the large number of images).

Answer (score 0):

The hex codes are Unicode characters. Here's a list of [all Unicode dingbat characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/dingbats/list.htm). Wherever that page lists U+somenumber, rewrite it as \somenumber in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a site where you can find the unicode of some characters:
http://unicode-table.com/

Answer (score 0):

I really like [graphemica.com](http://graphemica.com/%E2%9C%94) for detailed information, but [shapecatcher.com](http://shapecatcher.com/) can be really useful since it lets you draw out the symbol you're after.

Answer (score 0):

If you can copy the character, you can paste it into the [entity conversion calculator](http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html) and it will spit out the numeric value, as well as values you can use in css and js. It also looks up characters that you know the decimal value.